# Custom classes not changing in Spritekit .sks files

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I've been working with SpriteKit a bit and can't figure out this issue I'm having with custom classes in .sks files. Below is the sceneDidLoad method you'd find in a newly created SpriteKit project:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
// including entities and graphs.
GKScene *scene = [GKScene sceneWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];

// Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
GameScene *sceneNode = (GameScene *)scene.rootNode;

// Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
sceneNode.entities = [scene.entities mutableCopy];
sceneNode.graphs = [scene.graphs mutableCopy];

// Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
sceneNode.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;

// Present the scene
[skView presentScene:sceneNode];

skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
}
```

Nothing too crazy - it just loads an .sks file called GameScene, finds its root node (which is a GameScene type due to the custom class in the .sks being set to that), and pushes it to the screen.

The issue I'm having is that when I change this .sks file and the pertaining classes, the root node never adopts the custom class. The .sks file is being found by the sceneWithFileNamed method, as an invalid name will cause the method to return nil, while it currently returns a scene (but with a normal SKScene root node rather than my custom class). This causes my project to crash when I try to assign the scene entities to the sceneNode, which is not a built-in property of SKScene.

Here's my modified version, which only includes two edits:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Load 'MenuScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
// including entities and graphs.
GKScene *scene = [GKScene sceneWithFileNamed:@"MenuScene"];

// Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
MenuScene *sceneNode = (MenuScene *)scene.rootNode;

// Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
sceneNode.entities = [scene.entities mutableCopy];
sceneNode.graphs = [scene.graphs mutableCopy];

// Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
sceneNode.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;

// Present the scene
[skView presentScene:sceneNode];

skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
}
```

Here's the MenuScene.h file:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import <GameplayKit/GameplayKit.h>

@interface MenuScene : SKScene

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray<GKEntity *> *entities;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, GKGraph *> *graphs;

@end
```

Maybe even more interestingly, I can change the custom class of the GameScene .sks, but the code runs as though nothing changed.

Am I missing something, or are custom classes broken?

**Update:** I've tried putting the module name in the field below the custom class in the .sks inspector, but it hasn't worked out. Here's a link to the post that described that solution: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25620

Comment: Did you declare the entities array in your new custom class? There will be an entities array in the GameScene file as an example. You'll need graphs as well.

Comment: Yup! The MenuScene file was more or less a complete rip-off of the GameScene class, just to get my feet wet. I'll go ahead and add the MenuScene.h file to the question.

Comment: It would also help if you could show how you've modified `viewDidLoad` to present `menuScene`.

Comment: Done and done. Only the two edits were made. The MenuScene.m file is essentially bare. The sceneDidLoad() function is never called, if it's relevant.

Comment: In the MenuScene.sks did you set custom class to `MenuScene`?

Comment: I did - but the .sks files just don't seem to react to any change in the Custom Class field. I even went as far as to change the custom class in the functioning GameScene .sks to MenuScene, and the project just doesn't seem to acknowledge the change.

Comment: You might just need to do Ctrl-S to explicitly save the change. Maybe update your Xcode too, there is a new version 8.1